# MPU9150 On Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Had anyone had any luck getting the MPU9150 9-DOF chip to work well with ROS on the beagle bone black running Ubuntu and ROS Hydro? I'm aware of BB_ROS, but wanted to try to stick to running Ubuntu not Angstrom.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168261/mpu9150-on-hydro/) by [illogical_vectors](https://answers.ros.org/users/18266/illogical_vectors/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't used it personally, but you should be able to check out the bb_mpu9150 package from github https://github.com/vmayoral/bb_mpu9150 and build it on Ubuntu with Hydro.

Note that that node is publishing the IMU information as a std_msgs/String instead of as a sensor_msgs/Imu message; you'll probably need to upgrade it to sensor_msgs/Imu if you want to use it with other ROS nodes that make use of IMU data.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0